# Access table design

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the following requirement for an Access table and I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to design the table. I'm not sure if what I have is the best practice in this case.

table fields are name, Status, Date
each name will have minimum three status, and they change every month and then stop at Open. the date for each status change has to be captures in the database.

Example :

```
Name    |   Status  |   Date  
--------+-----------+------------------
name1   |   N/A     |   April  
name2   |   N/A     |   April  
name1   |   Open    |   May  
name2   |   N/A     |   May  
name1   |   closed  |   June  
name1   |   open    |   July
```

Comment: I don't really see any obvious issues, is there a particular scenario that you are unsure about?

Comment: @Newd I have over a thousand name and if I create a new record line for every name that means 3 times the records. I'm not sure if that is the best way to do it... I mean from a normalization point of view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the normalized point of view you need 4 tables total
1st table the **master** table

```
Name    |   Status  |   Date (month ?)   
--------+-----------+--------  
1       |   1       |   4  
2       |   3       |   5
```

2nd table the names table

```
ID      |   Names  
--------+-----------
1       |   name1   
2       |   name2
```

3rd table **status** table

```
    ID      |   Status
    --------+-----------
    1       |   N/A
    2       |   Open
    3       |   closed
```

4th table **Months**

```
ID      |   Month
--------+-----------
1       |   January
2       |   February
........|............
12      |   December
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I have thought about this particular setup a number of times myself.  I inherited a database that uses the format that you have posted.

While I don't think that setup is bad, another idea that I had was to create 3 checkbox fields that belong to each status to show progress.  Then there would be 3 date fields, each one pertaining to when the checkbox was checked off.

That would cut the number of records down by 2/3rds but again.  I think it is more of a matter of opinion.

Comment: from your solution I derive the following: creating a data field for each status and put the date that status took effect on...  thank you,

Comment: Ya that would work, so basically instead of having the checkbox's you just have the date fields.  You can then use those date fields, which means the presence of a date would effectively tell you that what the current status is.   Though I would just be cautious that you might be creating more work for yourself in the future with regards to queries.   Instead of `WHERE StatusA = True` you will need to need to work with it in a way like `WHERE IIF(DateA <> Null, 1, 0) = 1`.  That is very rough untested code but you get the idea.

Comment: @natali Your data sample shows 4 rows for *"name1"*.  Will you discard the information from one of those rows so that you can fit the rest into a single row with 3 status and 3 date values?

Comment: @HansUp, instead of having a row for each Status change and Data, I will create them as data filed, a check box for the status and a date field for the date 
N/a - N'A date - No - No Date - yes - Yes date

Comment: @natali What he means is that if you are going to have the same status twice on the same name then you can't use the three checkbox method.  If there is an undetermined amount of status that will be applied per name than you won't be able to keep them all on the same record and will likely have to stick with your current system.

Comment: oh, I see, no this was a typo. the status changes only once. thank you,

Comment: I thought that was the case, though HansUp's keen eye spotted the wording `minimum three status` I think.